# I can't get the time to increment in hours

Tags: python, class, while-loop, timedelta, class-method

Beginner and first time asker here! I’ve run into a problem with my first project.

I’m trying to write a class method that adds an hour on to the current time for every 180 within a big number.

I’m only testing a basic version at the moment, but I cant get it to work, the hour stays the same despite incrementing the hour variable.

(e.g. if the time now was 1:00pm and the user typed 540 cases, it would return:

> “360 should be remaining at: 2:00pm”
> “180 should be remaining at
> 3:00pm” “0 should be remaining at 4:00pm”

What it actually does is:

> “360 should be remaining at: 2:00pm”
> “180 should be remaining at 2:00pm”
> “0 should be remaining at 2:00pm”

```
def hourly_time_formula(self):

        
        c = self.cases

        hour = 1 
        nextHour = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours = hour) 
        neat_time = nextHour.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        

        if c > 180:
            while c >= 180:
                ihour += 1    
                c -= 180
                print(f"{c - 180} should be remaining at {neat_time}")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome, please check the description of the tags you add. The python-3.x tag should not be used on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating the `neat_time` variable. This is what you likely want:

```py
def hourly_time_formula(self):
    c = self.cases

    hour = 0

    if c > 180:
        while c >= 180:
            hour += 1    
            c -= 180
            nextHour = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours = hour) 
            neat_time = nextHour.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

            print(f"{c - 180} should be remaining at {neat_time}")
```